# 'No suitable driver found..' on AWS, works locally

Tags: postgresql, sqlexception, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I made a ktor application using exposed for db stuff and it works perfectly fine on my desktop, however when I deploy it on an AWS EC2 instance I get following error

> Exposed - Transaction attempt #0 failed: No suitable driver found for
> jdbc:postgresql://com.com:5432/DBName. Statement(s): null
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://
> at
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
> org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$connect$10.invoke(Database.kt:206)
> org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$connect$10.invoke(Database.kt:206)
> org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$doConnect$3.invoke(Database.kt:127)
> org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database$Companion$doConnect$3.invoke(Database.kt:128)

and so on.

Here's the connection:

```
Database.connect(DB_URL, driver = "org.postgresql.Driver", user = DB_USER, password = B_PW)
```

I've tried it with both, but no luck.

```
implementation("com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng:pgjdbc-ng:0.8.9")
implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.3")
```

I found potential solutions for Spring Boot (e.g. setting SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME) but I have no clue how I can relate this to ktor/exposed if even possible.

Answer (score 0):

nvfm
works now. aws magic, idk

edit:
com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver did not work at all so I tried to switch it but org.postgresql.Driver also did nothing at first. looked at the logs, same error as before.
after a while AWS' health thingy switched to Ok and it seems to work just fine now.